# Tomcat: not appending trailing "/" when finding a directory

Tags: tomcat

I deployed a .war archive in Tomcat 7.0.22 (Java 1.6, MacOS Lion). The war is called "myapp.war" and so Tomcat is serving http://localhost/myapp (having expanded the war in /webapps/myapp). This is the usual behavious

When accessing a url that corresponds to a directory, it should append "/" . For having static files (.css, .js..) working correctly, this is needed, but while with the sample sites that ship with Tomcat this works (for example visiting `http://127.0.0.1:8080/examples` suddenly remaps to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/examples/`), on my site tomcat doesn't add any "/" making the search for static files broken. When manually calling `localhost:8080/myapp/` (<-- I add the slash) everything works fine.

What should be going on? Mind that I haven't touched any Tomcat setting, I'm just experimenting with what comes out directly from Apache's zip file!

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that `http://localhost/myapp` *does not* generate a 302 redirect to `http://localhost/myapp/`?

Comment: yes, exactly. thanks for taking intereset

Comment: Hi pistaccio! `.war` file is roughly a renamed zip file. With that in mind if you open it and check the URL mapping on `WEB-INF/web.xml` file inside it you could experiment what it has. [This post about trailing slash](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Tomcat-trailing-slashes-and-welcome-files-td4684494.html) gives options what you could do when you found out what you had there!

Comment: I think you need to post more info, ideally your web.xml and/or @Servlet mappings. Have you deleted index.jsp? Try creating a .war without adding any servlet and see if that works (leaving index.jsp intact).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should explain more about your situation. As @mico has told here is a solution:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Jersey Filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>your package name(s)</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
            <param-value>.*\.jsp|.*\.css|.*\.png|.*\.js|.*\.gif|.*\.jpg</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Jersey Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The idea on solution based on:

> defining Jersey ServletContainer as a filter instead of a servlet

Here you can read more: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Tomcat-trailing-slashes-and-welcome-files-td4684494.html

[Here](http://grokbase.com/p/tomcat.apache.org/users/2004/12/re-tomcat-redirecting-when-base-uri-doesnt-have-trailing-slash/153j46fqqniwwojwzs67xuouyhhm) says that: `If you have a '/*' mapping, then Tomcat won't redirect`

One more: you should see how tomcat logs your request and decide the main problem.