# tomcat 7.0.56 windows (eclipse) trailing slash appended; tomcat 7.0.28 linux (deployed war) trailing slash not appended

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, servlets

I am new to configuring Tomcat server, mapping Java web application paths.

I got an Apache CXF web service which is using the following web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>KiiktatServices webszolgáltatás (Apache CXF)</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>static-welcome-file</param-name>
      <param-value>/services.html</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>static-resources-list</param-name>
      <param-value>/services.html</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<!--   <servlet-mapping> -->
<!--     <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name> -->
<!--     <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern> -->
<!--   </servlet-mapping> -->
<!--   <servlet-mapping> -->
<!--    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name> -->
<!--    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> -->
<!--   </servlet-mapping> -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
<!--    <welcome-file-list> -->
<!--        <welcome-file>services.html</welcome-file> -->
<!--    </welcome-file-list> -->
</web-app>
```

By default Apache CXF webservice provides a uniform webservices description page
which I need to change to a more informative, styled page. 
There is a possibility to provide az init-param to CXF which takes a static-welcome-file. 
I mapped the CXF servlet to `<Tomcat Context path>/*` as the above `web.xml` code section shows.

I also have some static CSS, JS resources which I had to map to `default` servlet to make it work, when I mapped it to `cxf` servlet it not worked.

When I start this combination on localhost Windows Tomcat 7.0.56 server in Eclipse, it appends a trailing slash to the end of the contextpath and thus `services.html` shows up with CSS, JS perfectly.

After this I create a WAR from project. There is a `(WebContent/)META-INF/context.xml` bundled into the WAR, but I also got a separate context.xml (named as the WAR's name) in `conf/Catalina/localhost/{war.name}.xml` that takes precedence over the bundled-in context.xml where I reference database connections, for the purpose of virtual hosting. But I not defined docBase, nor path in `<Context>`'s, so they are not relevant.

When I deploy this WAR to a Tomcat-7.0.28 on a Debian, it will not put the trailing slash at the end of the path.
The `services.html` static-html-page still shows but the JS, CSS is broken. After I manually put a trailing slash the page shows properly.

There are commented sections in the web.xml, those are part of another solution. There I am mapping the webservice to `/services/*` to `cxf` servlet, and not using its built in `static-welcome-file` init-parameter. Also, I am using `welcome-file` for `default` servlet and map the default servlet to `/*` instead. The result is the same, it puts trailing slash on my local dev machine, and works properly but not puts trailing slash after deployment as WAR on the Linux Tomcat.

I have been struggling with this problem for several days now. I know that there are similar problems, I have searched here and elsewhere but not found the solution.

Here it is stated that if I got `/*` mapping, then Tomcat won't redirect, but it is redirecting on localhost windows...
[Tomcat: not appending trailing "/" when finding a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852396/tomcat-not-appending-trailing-when-finding-a-directory)

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely break your whole server if you map something to `/*` and then change the mapping of `DefaultServlet` to be something other than `/`. The `DefaultServlet` handles things like adding trailing slashes when there is a directory involved, resolving welcome-files, etc. You have eclipsed that configuration by having your `cxf` servlet handle everything.

I think you want to use more care when mapping the `cxf` servlet.

Comment: Thank you, I made it work based on your suggestion. I mapped cxf servlet to url-pattern of '/services/*' and I mapped DefaultServlet to '/'. It also works I if map cxf to '/*', and DefaultServlet to '/' but I think it is cleaner if I don't let cxf mix with the static resources path. What I don't get now, why did it work with the incorrect, overlapping mapping the expected way in Eclipse?